# android Volley, What is the difference between cancelAll and stop method in RequestQueue

Tags: android, multithreading, http, android-volley

1. What is the difference between cancelAll and stop method in RequestQueue.
2. ImageLoader in listview adapter, will it load image again if the previous request return error? If not, how to make ImageLoader clear the error status, and forcely reload the image.
3. How to use Volley in IntentService, as I know IntentService need to run in single thread mode.

Comment: @btoueg what's you suggestion for this title then? :-)

Comment: My suggestion is to split it into 3 different SO questions.

Answer (score 0):

Third question :you don't need use volley in intentSevice volley cant handle it ,volley run in seperate thread than UI thread